# Parallel lines and corresponding angles.

Tags: geometry

[image: Figure]

In the figure shown, a,b and c are measures of the three angles and RQ is parallel to NO and PQ is parallel to MN.

- Quantity A: a
- Quantity B: b+c

Options:

- Quantity A is greater than Quantity B
- Quantity B is greater than Quantity A
- Quantity A is equal to Quantity B
- Relationship Cannot be determined

How to quickly visualize and solve this? 
Answer is C i.e. Both are equal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The angle $c$ is equal to the angle $P\hat RQ$. So, $c+b+R\hat PQ=180^\circ$. But $a+R\hat PQ=180^\circ$ too and therefore $a=b+c$.